# Bulk Emailing using Organisation GSuite Email

Tags: gmail, email-validation, bulk-email

I am working on a bulk email grabber that will  which I will use my organization's email to send out an email out to about 500+ email users. Does Gsuite allow for that or will these emails be flagged as spam?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends, you have your domain reputation, your DKIM (that could be enabled or not for your domain), your previouse sendings etc. You may setup https://postmaster.google.com/ for monitoring your sender reputation.